# Splitting Netbeans Jar File

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jar, build

I'm working on a project which is basically a game engine, used to make other games. I am working in Netbeans. My project has two parts, the engine itself, and the game core which is being ran. I would like to modify the build.xml so that when the project builds, it takes one group of packages, and compiles them into a jar, (the game core), and the rest gets compiled into a second jar, and places the first jar inside of an asset folder in the second jar. Is this possible, or do I have to keep building this manually?

I currently know nothing about ant builds, despite my research.

Comment: Can you split the Netbeans project into two projects corresponding to the two jars and make the one project depend on the other?

Comment: I was originally planning on that, but I was having issues with git syncing. Anyways, I found a way to accomplish my goal, with a bit more research of ant. I'm closing this question now. Thank you for your help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using this code.

```
<project name="WraithEngine2" basedir="." default="main">
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build"/>
    <delete dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/dist"/>
</target>
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1"/>
    <mkdir dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes2"/>
    <mkdir dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/dist"/>
    <mkdir dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1/Assets"/>
    <mkdir dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1/Native"/>
    <javac srcdir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/src" destdir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1">
        <include name="build/**"/>
    </javac>
    <javac srcdir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/src" destdir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes2">
        <include name="run/**"/>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1/Assets">
        <fileset dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/src/Assets"/>
    </copy>
    <copy todir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1/Native">
        <fileset dir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/src/Native"/>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/dist/WraithGame.jar"
         basedir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes2">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="run.wraith.engine.WraithEngineGame"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <copy file="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/dist/WraithGame.jar" todir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1/Native"/>
    <jar destfile="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/dist/WraithEngine.jar"
         basedir="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/build/classes1">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="build.games.wraithaven.core.WraithEngine"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="/home/thedudefromci/NetBeansProjects/WraithEngine2/dist/WraithEngine.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>
<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```